# how to Render a PartialView inside a main view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an application, where I need to add a create View to enter data inside the Index View (where I'm showing all the data in a table from the database), to enter data from the same view. The Create View has rendered without any problem, but an error occurs on postback: `error="child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions"`.

**Controller:**

```
// GET: /Brands/
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await db.Brands.ToListAsync());
}

// GET: /Brands/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return PartialView("_Create", new BootstrapModalTest.Models.Brand());
}

// POST: /Brands/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="BrandId,BrandName,BrandCode")] Brand brand)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Brands.Add(brand);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return PartialView("_Create", brand);
    }

    return PartialView("_Create", brand);
}
```

**Here is `Index.cshtml`:**

```
div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" style=" padding:2px 7px 0px 6px;"><h4>Frames</h4></div>

<div class="panel-body " style="padding:4px;">
    @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "Brands");}
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered>
    // some data
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: m getting a error "child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions"

Comment: Explain that in the question (not in comments!)

Comment: this error accurs on postback

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@Html.Partial("../Controller/View", model)
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml", model)
```

Adding in the correct path to the "_Create" view as per your Create method.
In turn the create method can be deleted.